# Set Width and Height Scale in DocumentApp InlineImage via Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, document, google-docs-api

The DocumentApp service in Apps Script has an [`InlineImage`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-image) class to manipulate images in a Google Doc. I see it's `setWidth()` and `setHeight()` methods, but in the Google Doc UI, there's also a "Width Scale" and "Height Scale" property.

[image: Google Doc Image options]

Is it possible to change these via Apps Script?

Comment: Yes. Use [setHeight(height)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-image#setheightheight) & [setWidth(width)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-image#setwidthwidth)

Comment: There are no other options/methods that you can use other than the one mentioned by @Boris. Just take in mind that the `height` and `width` values are in `pixels`